# Get the process id of application by clicking on the icon in the taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pid, visual-studio-2019

I want to get the process id by clicking on the icon in the taskbar to get an unique identifier, because it could be the case, that this application is opend multiple times.

Is there any method or sth. that gives me the process id of the application i have put my focus on?

I want to get information from an application, but before this can happen, i need to know, which application he wants to track, because it can happen, that this application is opened multiple times and that there are multiple application opened with different versions, but with the same names.

I have tried to find some existing examples on the internet, but it seems, that nobody had this problem until now.

The code below just gives me the ID of my own application, but instead, it should 'wait' until i have changed my focus on the application i click in the taskbar.

```
    private void TextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //wait until focus is set on new application
        {
           Process prcsToTrack =  Process.GetCurrentProcess();
           int processID = prcsToTrack.Id;
           TextBox1.Text = processID.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Maybe one of you has mastered this problem or some ideas and can show me some results.

Comment: [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) => `(idProcess = 0, idThread = 0,  Min/Max = EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART, flags = WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD)`. Or UI Automation.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please ask about the problem rather than your proposed solution.

Answer (score -1):

try the `this.Activated` event of the form/window you want to take the process id.

something like this

```
 private void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       var pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
       // do something
 }
```

Comment: The problem is, i dont know from which window the process id will be taken, because as i said, the user should choose from every application in the taskbar and i want to know which application he choosed, so that i can later get information about it.
The user has to choose one "Dynamcis NAV Development Environment" application, but most often there are 2-3 applications of the same kind opened and some other older or newer versions.